# Chrome 1px line visible when masking with SVG

Tags: css, svg, mask

I have an element that is being masked by a SVG shape. The shape is not the same size as the element, so I make it cover the whole element by setting `mask-size: cover`.

This works, but in Chrome and Safari this shows a 1px line where apparently the mask didn't cover the element 100%.

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rw0e3jLc/1/).

[image: 1px line]

Is there something to counter this with CSS? Or is this due to some buggy rendering of the browser?

Comment: You may like to read this article where it goes about masking: https://css-tricks.com/scooped-corners-in-2018/#use-css-gradient-mask

Comment: Did you figure something out?